# Why is angularjs url encoding my POST params?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, post, xmlhttprequest, urlencode

Here is the rest client in our service:

```
self.headers = {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

self.loginClient = $resource(self.baseUrl + '/users/login', {
        userId: '@userId',
        password: '@password'
    }, {
        save: {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: self.headers
        }
    });
```

I call it like this -

```
AuthService.loginClient.save({
        userId: self.user.email,
        password: self.user.password
    }).$promise.then(function (res) {
        // do stuff
    })
```

The URL path that the browser is hitting looks like this:

```
/users/login?password=XXXXXX&rememberMe=false&userId=XXXXXX
```

Can anyone tell what I have wrong here that is leading to the url encoding of my POST params? Please let me know what other info I can provide.

Comment: Why are you sending a password in the URL parameters?

Comment: It is an old endpoint. We are updating them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just pass the data to the action method.change the service like this

```
self.headers = {
        Accept: 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    };

self.loginClient = $resource(self.baseUrl + '/users/login',  {
        save: {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: self.headers
        }
    });
```

call it like this

```
AuthService.loginClient.save({},{
        userId: self.user.email,
        password: self.user.password
    })
```

Comment: This format works for our other services. I really am just wondering *why* it is encoding what should be sent as an object in the body.

Comment: Yeaaah..I was skeptical, but gave it a try. That didn't work for me.

Comment: I had to fiddle with what you had here, but I got it working. It was the right track ultimately. Updated your answer